# Why are sweeptests ignoring collisions (read the edit)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have an object that is moved according to the key arrows, like a character controller. The sweeptest is thrown every `Update()` that it moves, but if you keep pressing the button, it goes through. By the way, am not using Unity physics, so any solution that implies the use of `OnCollision()` voids doesn´t work

```
void Update()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed; 
    velocity.x = horizontal;//y axis adds gravity, but is omitted here to focus on the relevant

    Vector3 movement = velocity * Time.deltaTime;

    if (movement != Vector3.zero)
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (rb.SweepTest(movement, out hit, movement.magnitude))
        {
            if (hit.collider)
            {
                Vector3 moveToColl = movement / movement.magnitude * hit.distance;//gives hit.distance vector                 
                transform.position += moveToColl;

                movement = Vector3.zero;//because movement has already been done.
                velocity = movement;
            }
        }
    }

    this.transform.Translate(movement, Space.World);
}
```

Since I thought the problem was the gameObject overlapping with the collider, I´ve tried moving the gameObject behind before doing the sweeptest (because sweeptests, for some reason, don´t allow for layermasks) and then incresing its length to keep the same collision.

```
Vector3 behindVector = movement / 100;

transform.position -= behindVector;
float maxDistance = movement.magnitude;
maxDistance += maxDistance / 100;// same as movement.magnitude + behindVector.magnitude
```

// the same, but then maxDistance replaces movement.magnitude in the sweeptest´s length.
While this significantly reduced the problem, there were still frames where the object would go through a wall, specially if the distance was close or after a change in direction and jumping (am sorry: am not exactly sure. I tried to figure out what was it, but I didn´t really get it. It seems more often if you get close to a wall and try to go through, then move in the opposite direction and try again, specially if the velocity.y is also modified, which makes me think it´s related to the vector´s magnitude). 
The other solution that I tried was this:

```
if (hit.collider)
{
   Vector3 moveToColl = movement / movement.magnitude * hit.distance;//gives hit.distance vector
   moveToColl *= 0.9f;
   float minimum = 0.001f;
   if (moveToColl.magnitude > minimum)
   {
       transform.position += moveToColl;
   }
   movement = Vector3.zero;//these two are kept outside
   velocity = movement;
}
```

So moving the object less than it´s supposed to would prevent the overlap, but if the 0.9f is bigger, like 0.999f, the collisions are basically null again. If we try 0.6f instead, it works almost perfectly, but this has two problems. First, am not even completely sure if I got rid of the problem, it just seems so. Second, this movement is wrong and if that float is smaller (which again, improves the collision), then the gap between both objects is more noticeable, even if it´s not that much. 
I even tried both approaches at once, but it gave me a weird vibration of the object because this two lines modify its position: `transform.position -= behindVector;`// and `transform.position += moveToColl`;

EDIT: Since the problem is caused by float´s lack of precision and colliders overlapping, I thought of another solution, but I need help for the last part.
It´s about subtracting a Vector3 offset from the moveToColl vector. First, we assume that is 0.1f on the X axis (direction needs to be opposite to moveToColl.x, so if that is negative, this is positive)  and use this formula to get the Y value: 0.1f * moveToColl.y / moveToColl.x. So we end with the Vector3 like (0.1f, Y value, weIgnoreZAxisInThisExample). We subtract this from the moveToColl vector and we get a new vector that keeps the same direction, but doesn´t move those extra 0.1f in X and whatever it is in Y to keep that direction. If we want the other axis, the formula is the same but we invert all axes. The first exaple works fine with walls. Because is subtracting 0.1f regardless of the y velocity it never goes through (assuming that value is enough). The reason the sweeptest missed the collisions more frequently while jumping, was that the change in y decreased the x offset (since we were multiplying the vector by 0.9f, that 0.1f was subtracted to the direction instead of the the x axis. Now is constant). But this only works with perfect vertical or horizontal lines. If is a slope, the offset is wrong. I discovered that the offset needs to be perpendicular to the surface since the closest distance is always perpendicular. Against walls it worked fine because the x axis was perpendicular, so it was as simple as subtracting the offset directly and keeping the direction. But now is not not axis-aligned.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyzJx.png)

Sorry, the offset is -0.1, 0.1. I forgot to place the - and it goes to the opposite direction. The formula will give, for example, the purple vector to get the offset (I know that I really draw the x and y offsets, because I really want those). The correct vector would start at the hit. point and end where the green and black lines intersect (that´s what am looking for). There´s also an orage dot inside of the green offset, which is wrong, since the distance between that and the blue line is clearly less than is supposed to; so if the formula gave that point it would be bad (although am not entirely sure if that is possible, so tell me if you know). In any case, the bigger the distance, the easier it is to see that is not colliding. That was why I wanted the closest possible distance. By the way, the 0.1f was just an example. Does anyone know which is the closest distance where you can safely detect the collision?

Comment: You would be better off using Unity Physics..... That being said... What does your collider look like? What kind of collider are you using?

Comment: Also SweepTest tends to fail when the test starts on an object which is already "collided".... Combine this with "float" rounding problems and calculation problems...  This means that some times your sweeptest will start on an object that is already inside the collision box even by a tiny tiny fraction.... So this will make SeepTest fail.... So you cannot rely solely on SweepTest

Answer (score 0):

Even though this might not be the exact answer to the OP's problem it might be useful for those who reach here searching in Google.

This is a hard to debug problem.  But it could be caused by a known issue with the SweepTest in some cases.

When the sweep test starts on an already "collided" object... meaning that it starts with the object already inside the collider even if it is by a tiny tiny fraction then the sweep test will fail.

Combine that with the precision problems of the "float" type and you have the perfect bug in your game.

This a discussion that might be useful to understand the problem: [SweepTest issue](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-bug-rigidbody-sweeptestall-occasionally-missing-colliders-seemingly-at-random.472174/)

The problem might be solved or mitigated by using [ComputePenetration](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ComputePenetration.html?_ga=2.20462267.227645235.1576855450-733007931.1576855450), [ClosestPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ClosestPoint.html?_ga=2.20462267.227645235.1576855450-733007931.1576855450) or combination of.

Other collision problems could be fixed by changing the [CollisionDetectionMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html?_ga=2.87027995.227645235.1576855450-733007931.1576855450) on your rigid bodies.

Another idea (not sure if this will help) is trying to set EdgeRadius in your collision object??? Worth the shot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my first solution of moving the object backwards was fine, but is better like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (movement != Vector3.zero)
    {
        float maxDistance = movement.magnitude;
        Vector3 behindVector = movement * (0.003f / maxDistance);
        transform.position -= behindVector;
        maxDistance += 0.003f;//movement.magnitude + behindVector.magnitude
        //then do the sweepTest
    }
}
```

However, now I see that I need to increase the  0.003f offset more for certain situations. To prevent collisions with an object that´s behind the player, you need to check if the hit.distance is > offset and ignore the rest of collisions.